# HTML5 Canvas drawImage issue

Tags: html, canvas, crop, drawimage

I am using a **[cropper.js library](http://dev.vizuina.com/cropper/)** to get the cropping coordinates from the image and then i am creating a canvas to download the cropped image.

i have fixed cropping dimensions max at 200x200 pixels

The issue is that the cropped image does not stretch fully to 200 px width of the canvas that it should. See the image below

[image]

[Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RgGJh/1/) (thanks @entio for the fiddle)

Below is the code

```
<body>
        <img src="Desert.jpg" id="image" style="float:left;"/>
        <canvas id="myCanvas" style="height:200px; width:200px; position:absolute; right:50px; top:20px; border:1px dotted black;"></canvas>
        <div>
        <label><em>y</em>coordinate</label>                                
        <input type="text" name="y" id="y-1" class="form-control" value="0" />

        <label><em>x</em> coordinate</label>                                
        <input type="text" name="x" id="x-1" class="form-control" value="0" />

        <label>Selected <em>width</em></label>                                
        <input type="text" name="width" id="width-1" class="form-control" value="0" />

        <label>Selected <em>height</em></label>                                
        <input type="text" name="width" id="height-1" class="form-control" value="0" />                                
     </div>                   

    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById('image').onload = function() {
            new Cropper(image, {
                // options              
                max_width: 200,
                max_height: 200,                    
                update: function(coordinates) {
                    console.log(coordinates);
                    console.log(image);                     
                    for (var i in coordinates) {
                        document.getElementById(i + '-1').value = coordinates[i];
                    }
                    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
                    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');                  
                    context.drawImage(image, coordinates['x'],coordinates['y'], coordinates['width'],coordinates['height'], 0, 0, 200, 200);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

Any help ?

Comment: Looks like given coordinates are wrong.. what does console.log(coordinates) output?

Comment: it gives me a object with four keys as follows -
Object {x: 214, y: 121, width: 250, height: 250}

Comment: I don't think there is a issue with that..because even if put coordinates there manually...still image doesn't stretch to full width.

Comment: im trying to make a fiddle but something does not wanna work...

Comment: okay, fiddle is settled. Had an issue with width and height being 0; here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/RgGJh/1/

Comment: Put width and height attributes to #myCanvas ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Canvas use width and height attributes.

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="200" style="height:200px; width:200px; posit...
```

http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html

*'The width attribute defaults to 300, and the height attribute defaults to 150.'* So it does not have the size you want unless you specify if.

**FIDDLE:**
http://jsfiddle.net/RgGJh/2/

Comment: CHEERS...that did the job..thanks man !
Didn't click to me that i was missing this as i had already given height and width in style attribute.
Silly one...wasted a good few hours on this.